# Arduino LED 9 V transistor with a common ground

Tags: arduino, transistors, led

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5a9Ue.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am kind of new to building my own electronics.

I am building a stargate with 3D printed parts. When I soldered all the LEDs together, I connected them in series (9 sets of 3 LEDs) with a common ground as that is how I had seen others do it in the 3D printing community. After getting all of the soldering done, I glued the cover on it and when testing realized that in series the rduino doesn't have enough power to light the LEDs completely, they do turn on but barely visible.

It's too late to go back and re-solder them in parallel since I have already glued all the plastic parts together using 3D Gloop which bonds the PLA plastic together chemically.

What I need to do is provide a 9V charge to each set of 3 lights and I understand from my google searches and youtube that I can do that with transistors.

All the videos and information I have seen show the transistor using the ground between the collector and emitter to regulate the flow with the base connected to the digital pin of the Arduino to activate it. Since I wired all the sets of LEDs to a common ground and they need to be turned on individually, I need to run the 9V through the transistors to the 9 sets of LEDs individually and I'm really not sure what type of resistor to use.

The LEDs already have 220 ohm resistors connected inside the stargate if that helps. Any assistance would be appreciated since this is a graduation present for my nephew.

[image: Original schematic]

Comment: This is why you should always test the circuit before putting it in an enclosure! That being said, do you have any access to the inside of the enclosure? or do you only now have access to the wires going in? A schematic and a photo would help here

Comment: I only have access to the wires going in, added a picture. Don't have a schematic with me right now.

Comment: There is a built in schematic editor here. If you edit the question you can draw one. Just press ctrl+M, or click the schematic editor symbol. And your picture is before it is assembled. What would be helpful is a properly drawn schematic, and a picture of it as it is now, so we can see what wires you have access to, and you can point them out ini the schematic

Comment: Added a schematic, hope that helps

Comment: I meant a schematic of what you have right now, rather than what you want. Then label on the schematic what wires are actually available

Comment: Found the schematic for the original circuit and added it.

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg if you have implemented the "original" circuit then it will work at 9V or 12V. Do you have transistors Q1 to Q9 in your circuit?

Comment: I honestly overlooked the Q1-Q9 when assembling, I'm really starting to realize how little I know about this stuff, but thank you everyone for your responses I am learning a lot. So if I get the BC548 Transistors and add them into the circuit it sounds like it should work?

Comment: If you are following a schematic, you should *always* make sure you use the right components. You should never omit a component unless you understand *why* you are doing it. Unless you just forgot?

Comment: Honestly, someone in the 3d printing community had put together a graphical representation of this circuit and I was following that since I am not really familiar at how to read circuit diagrams, I guess they left out the transistors in the graphical representation so I missed it. This whole project has been quite a learning experience for me.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I have added an answer for you, confirming that adding the transistors will work. When I was a beginner, I found that I learned more from failing and figuring out what went wrong than I did when things just worked! SO don't look at it as a negative thing. Also, that's a cool looking project!

Comment: Yeah, I learn more from my failures as well, and there have been a lot of hoops to jump through with this one. Here is a link to the project on thingiverse if you are interested in seeing what the whole thing looks like, several people have posted pictures on there of their completed builds: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1603423

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg I'm looking at the schematic diagram you posted and I'm 99.9% confident that the Arduino's digital I/O (DIO) pins will quickly be destroyed, or Q1-Q9 will be destroyed, or both.  The schematic is missing some crucial components: there must be a resistor between each DIO pin and the base of its corresponding transistor. This "current limiting" resistor limits the amount of current that is sourced (that flows) from a DIO pin into the base of its Q* transistor. Without these current limiting resistors (one resistor per DIO pin) you'll fry the DIO pins or the Q1-Q9 transistors.

Comment: I was going to use a 2.2k resistor between the DIO and the base of the resistor

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg my apologies for my schematics, Jim fischer is correct, you will need current limiting resistors. Unfortunately, I was editing an old schematic and didnt pay enough attention to detail. Fortunately, Jim pointed out my mistakes so I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update, I ordered a variety pack of transistors from amazon and it should be here tomorrow to start testing. Might be a dumb question, but is there a difference between resistors and current limiting resistors? I have a variety pack of resistors already and not sure if I have the right ones.

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg nope, they should be fine to use. Variety packs are usually 1/4W, so just calculate the power dissipated ( P = I*V ) and as long as it is less than 0.25W you will be fine! By the way, if you found my answer helpful, click the little 'Up' arrow next to it. If you find it does answer your question, click the tick to accept it as correct.

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg The terminology "current limiting resistor" describes a resistor whose job is to set the maximum current that can flow through a circuit branch that's connected in series with the resistor. The current is calculated via Ohm's law, I_R=V_R/R, where V_R is the voltage across resistor R, and I_R is the current flowing through resistor R. In your schematic, resistors R1-R9 are current limiting resistors; each resistor limits the maximum current that can flow through its series-connected LEDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when you were assembling your circuit, you forgot to add the transistors Q1-Q9 in your circuit. These are needed to allow the Arduino to control when the LEDs turn on/off without supplying them directly, by wiring them to the transistor base, hence you won't need to worry about how much current is available from the Arduino pin.

If you have access to the GND wires from each column of LEDs, this is where you should place the transistor.

Once you have fitted it, you should find that you can control the LEDs with the Arduino pins.

If making any similar projects in the future and you are following a schematic, read it carefully, and perhaps do some Googling or ask here about any parts of a circuit you are unsure about. It is always good to try and understand how something works before putting it together, as that way if you run into problems, it makes fault finding a lot easier.

If you have just a single common GND, then you will need to have a high side switch. You can use a PNP/NPN pair to do something like this. I have simulated the circuit for you so you can see how to connect it. This is probably the easiest, and cheapest way to resolve your issue.

To have the LEDs OFF:

[image]

And to turn them ON:

[image]

The logic pin (that switches from 0 to 1) will be a 5V Arduino pin. If you do not have 5V available, it will also work with 3.3V:

[image]

This could also be a useful transistor configuration to remember if you ever need to switch a higher voltage for future circuits.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Given that I have hooked them all to the same ground, is it still possible for them to work properly if I add the transistor before the LEDs in the circuit instead of after? Also, I will be more careful in the future, this is really my first project and I really appreciate  the advice.

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg Oh I see! So you only have 1 common GND wire that you have access to? You haven't got a separate GND from each column and tied them together outside the stargate?

Comment: correct, I connected them all to the same GND wire when I soldered them together inside the gate. There was very little space for the wires and I thought it would make thing easier, I learned my lesson, lol.

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg I have edited my answer with something that should work for you. Please note that you will need to choose an NPN transistor that will be able to handle the current. The BC548 will probably get too hot with this circuit.

Comment: will that light them all up at once, or each set individually, or am I missing something? I mean I understand the concept I think, To do it individually I would just apply this circuit to each of the sets of 3 LEDs. I just need to determine the proper Transistor?

Comment: @DanielBrandenburg Yes, this will light them all up at once. If you wanted to do each column individually, then you can just use that NPN/PNP pair and put in on the power rail of each column, that is correct. If you were doing that, then the BC548 should be fine

Comment: @MCG FWIW, I think Q1 is installed backwards in each of your three schematics--i.e., Q1's emitter should be connected directly to BAT1's '+' terminal, and Q1's collector should be connected to the circuit node with R1..R5. As currently shown Q1's operating mode is "reverse active", but what's needed is "forward saturation" mode. Note that a PNP transistor's emitter voltage should be more positive than its collector voltage (VCE<0); in each of your circuits Q1's emitter voltage is more negative than its collector voltage (VCE>0); hence Q1 is operating in reverse active mode.

Comment: @MCG (cont.) Also, if Q1 is reconnected as I suggested with its emitter connected to BAT1's '+' terminal, you'll then need to add a current-limiting resistor between Q1's base and Q2's collector.  This resistor's value must ensure Q1 saturates (turns fully ON) when Q2 saturates (when it turns fully ON).  Likewise, there must be a current-limiting resistor connected in series between the 3V3 power source and Q2's base to limit the amount of current that's sourced into Q2's base.  Without these two current limiting resistors, Q1, Q2, or the 3V3 power source (e.g., the DIO pin) will be damaged.

Comment: @JimFischer Ahh, you are right, my apologies! I just rotated the part and placed it without checking! Rookie error! I started by drawing the circuit with MOSFETs, hence the resistor placement, then when replacing them with BJTs, I didn't pay attention to the simple things! Thank you for picking up on that! I'll make the adjustments now

Comment: @JimFischer schematic updated. Thanks again for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers you've already received, here is my suggestion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk3JFbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Resistor \$R_{LOAD}\$ is a "dummy" component; it is a placeholder for the actual circuit that you want to turn ON|OFF via Q1.  To solve for the values of the "current limiting" resistors R1 and R2 proceed as follows.

1. Determine the required current through the load, \$I_{LOAD}\$. For the purposes of this example assume \$I_{LOAD}=20\;mA\$. *(n.b. I'm assuming the LOAD circuit has one or more components that limit the LOAD current to 20 mA when Q1 is ON.)*
2. For Q1 choose a PNP transistor whose rated collector current \$I_C\ge2I_{LOAD}\$. I'll choose for Q1 an [ON Semiconductor *2N3906* PNP transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3906-D.pdf) whose \$I_C=200\;mA\$.
3. Using Q1's data sheet determine the forward current gain when Q1 is operating in saturation mode (fully ON): \$\beta_{SAT}=10\$.
4. Calculate Q1's base current when Q1 is operating in saturation mode:
   $$
   Q1.I_{B(SAT)}=\frac{Q1.I_{C(SAT)}}{Q1.\beta_{SAT}}=\frac{20\;mA}{10}=2\;mA
   $$
5. For Q2 chose an NPN transistor whose rated collector current \$I_C\ge 2\cdot Q1.I_{B(SAT)}\$. I'll chose an [ON Semiconductor *2N3904* NPN transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/PZT3904-D.pdf) whose \$I_C=200\;mA\$.
6. Using Q2's data sheet determine the forward current gain when Q2 is operating in saturation mode (fully ON): \$\beta_{SAT}=10\$.
7. Calculate Q2's base current when Q2 is operating in saturation mode: 
   $$
   Q2.I_{B(SAT)}=\frac{Q2.I_{C(SAT)}}{Q2.\beta_{SAT}}=\frac{2\;mA}{10}=200\;\mu A
   $$
8. Solve for R1. *(n.b. Use the 2N3904 and 2N3906 data sheets to find values for \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$ and \$V_{BE(SAT)}\$.)* *(n.b. On a PNP transistor, current flows OUT of the transistor's base lead, and \$V_{BE(SAT)}\lt0\;V\$, and \$V_{EB(SAT)}=-V_{BE(SAT)}\$.)*
   $$
   R1=\frac{V_{R1}}{I_{R1}}
   \\=\frac{V_{CC}-Q1.V_{EB(sat)}-Q2.V_{CE(sat)}}{Q1.I_{B(sat)}}
   \\=\frac{9\;V-0.8\;V-0.05\;V}{2\;mA}
   \\=4.08\;k\Omega
   $$
9. Choose R1's value as \$3.9\;k\Omega\pm5\;\%\$. *(n.b. Calculate R1's power dissipation when Q2 is ON: \$P=I^2R\$. Choose for R1 a resistor whose power dissipation spec is >=2x its calculated power dissipation.)*
10. Solve for R2. *(n.b. Use the microcontroller's data sheet to find \$V_{OH}\$ for the DIO pin. For example, assume we are using a [Microchip Technology](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf)* ATmega328P *microcontroller and 5 V logic; see Chapter 30 "Electrical Specifications" in the data sheet. Use the 2N3904 data sheet to find \$V_{BE(SAT)}\$.)*
    $$
    R2=\frac{V_{R2}}{I_{R2}}
    \\=\frac{DIO.V_{OH}-Q2.V_{BE(sat)}}{Q2.I_{B(sat)}}
    \\=\frac{4.2\;V-0.7\;V}{200\;\mu A}
    \\=17.5\;k\Omega
    $$
11. Choose R2's value as \$18\;k\Omega\pm5\;\%\$. *(n.b. Calculate R2's power dissipation when Q2 is ON. Choose for R2 a resistor whose power dissipation spec is >=2x its calculated power dissipation.)*

Comment: That is a lot more information than I thought I would get on here. As soon as my transistor kit gets here, I will be sure to reference this information while breadboarding my circuit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that the LED common side is ground, so you will need a high-side driver which requires more than one transistor per circuit. Or, you could use an IC that has multiple drivers. I have seen up to 8 per IC, this one has 4. Assuming that you have 5V available, three of these would be needed for your 9 LED circuits. This is a little overkill since it will drive both high and low, but right now I can't find a suitable high-side only driver. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/L293DNE/296-9518-5-ND/379724

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxuyQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How can anyone down-vote this?  THIS WILL WORK AND IT USES 3 PARTS INSTEAD OF 36!  (not counting the LEDs and series resistors that are already inside the Stargate)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. It will indeed work. I upvoted the answer. Definitely didn't deserve a downvote. Would be nice if people left comments explaining their reasons!

Comment: I found the idea interesting myself, wouldn't have down voted it. Wouldn't have a clue how to implement it, but I have learned a lot from my mistakes since asking this question and appreciate your response.